# How do you get the "Add my app to the springboard" notification to pop-up in Mobile Safari?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

For some websites/webapps, using Mobile Safari on the website causes a pop-up to come up advising the user that they can add the site/app to their home screen. I tried to replicate it but I can't figure it out.

Is there a JS library to do this or is there a meta tag to add to my html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of them use [add to home screen](http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen) from cubiq

Comment: EXACTLY the answer I was looking for.